# TinyMCE 3 and 4 not compatible with older Opera?

Tags: tinymce, opera, clipboard, paste

I use Opera v11.52 for an intranet 'web-based' project presently in production use. For a number of reasons, I prefer to constrain users to the 'older' Opera (prior to the webkit engine-switch versions)
I am using TinyMCE for WYSIWIG editing, but have been battling with the `paste` functionality. The problem is that whenever the user pastes (Ctrl+V) into the editor, it just freezes. The cursor keeps blinking, but you can never get it to respond to any input until the page is refreshed.
With TinyMCE 3, a javascript error is reported like so

```
Uncaught Error: INDEX_SIZE_ERR: DOM Exception 1
```

After much struggle, I decided to try TinyMCE 4. The behaviour is quite identical, except that I did not find ANY console error message.

Wanting to investigate further, I decided to check out the demo at the product home page: http://www.tinymce.com/index.php

While Chrome breezily displayed the editor and the rest, Opera 11.52 could only show a miserable textarea. This error, I found in my dragonfly console:

```
Syntax error at line 10 while loading:
butes:{align:"right"
--------------------^
expected '}', got <end of file>
Uncaught exception: ReferenceError: Undefined variable: tinymce

Error thrown at line 2, column 4 in http://www.tinymce.com/index.php:
tinymce.PluginManager.load('moxiemanager', '/js/moxiemanager/plugin.min.js');
```

This suggests to me that the opera engine may indeed be unsupported in both versions. Since I have no choice but to stick to Opera 11 for now, I would appreciate any FIX, WORKAROUND or even HACK that can help me out.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you should try removing the moxiemanager plugin.
It's a paid plugin and is not inculded when you download TinyMCE thus it causes problems.